# C++ scope resolution operator vs friend for accessing parent's protected variables

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

What is the right way to access a parent's protected variable?

---

```
template<typename T>
struct A
{
    A() : i(2) {}
protected:
    int i;
};
```

```
template<typename T>
struct B : public A
{
    void foo() { std::cout << A<T>::i << std::endl; }
};
```

---

This will correctly print out `2`.

Is there another way to do it with inheritance?

Should I instead of inheritance make **B** a friend?

Comment: A plain `i` will work fine. `A::i` is not needed. As far as what you're asking, this is entirely up to you. You are designing these classes, you decide what makes the most sense.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I updated my question to include templates.

Comment: In that case, `this->i` is much easier on one's fingers. Everything else I wrote still holds true.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?